# Java Nimbus Look & Feel RSyntaxTextArea Background Color

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus, rsyntaxtextarea

I'm using [`RSyntaxTextArea`](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea) which ultimately extends from `JTextArea`. When I change the look and feel to `Nimbus`, the text area is not affected the same way as the rest of the GUI which doesn't look nice.

This is the `Nimbus` theme code I used:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI;
import static javax.swing.UIManager.*;

public class SwingLookAndFeel
{
    static void setDarkNimbusLookAndFeel(JFrame frame) throws Exception
    {
        put("control", new Color(128, 128, 128));
        put("info", new Color(128, 128, 128));
        put("nimbusBase", new Color(18, 30, 49));
        put("nimbusAlertYellow", new Color(248, 187, 0));
        put("nimbusDisabledText", new Color(128, 128, 128));
        put("nimbusFocus", new Color(115, 164, 209));
        put("nimbusGreen", new Color(176, 179, 50));
        put("nimbusInfoBlue", new Color(66, 139, 221));
        put("nimbusLightBackground", new Color(18, 30, 49));
        put("nimbusOrange", new Color(191, 98, 4));
        put("nimbusRed", new Color(169, 46, 34));
        put("nimbusSelectedText", new Color(255, 255, 255));
        put("nimbusSelectionBackground", new Color(104, 93, 156));
        put("text", new Color(230, 230, 230));

        for (LookAndFeelInfo[] info : getInstalledLookAndFeels())
        {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
            {
                setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }

        refreshFrame(frame);
    }

    private static void refreshFrame(JFrame frame)
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            // frame.pack();
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder which `UIManager` keys are needed to modify the text area background color as well e.g. by setting the purple color from the `JTree` on the left as background color instead of white?

[image]

[Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/JavaUIDefaults.txt) is a list of `UIManager` keys I found but are any of them even helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea/wiki/Example:-Setting-the-theme) is described how to use themes specifically for `RSyntaxTextArea`. Using the provided `dark.xml` works fine:

[image]

```
private void changeStyleViaThemeXml() {
  try {
     Theme theme = Theme.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
           "/org/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/themes/dark.xml"));
     theme.apply(textArea);
  } catch (IOException ioe) { // Never happens
     ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```